# ListView header hide

Tags: android, android-listview

I beginner in android.

### I trying add header to ListView, but view is hide.

header view - test.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:padding="50dp"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:text="afassa"/>


    <View android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_width="2dp"
          android:id="@+id/line"
          android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
          android:background="#ffffff"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:id="@+id/ll"
        >
    <ListView android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:id="@+id/lv"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

add header

```
        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
        View v = View.inflate(this,R.layout.test,null);
        lv.addHeaderView(v);
        lv.setAdapter(aa);
```

### but view with "@+id/line" hide in header why?

Comment: You are setting header left side ?

Comment: No. Header must fill width.

Answer (score 0):

Its probably because of the 50dp padding you are doing in the TextView of test.xml.
Also you didnt say where the view would go in the relative layout, so the line is drawn on top of the textview. Also the color u have set is white and the width of the line is 2dp. your test.xl should look like:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:text="afassa"
          android:id="@+id/head"/>


<View android:layout_height="2dp"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:id="@+id/line"
      android:background="#000000"
      android:layout_below="@id/head"/></RelativeLayout>
```

Hope it works now.

Comment: Line must be vertical

Comment: I dont know if thats even possible.What are u trying to achieve here? Why a vertical line on top of a listview? Even in that case:
android:layout_height="50dp"-->give some constant value not match_parent
android:layout_width="2dp"

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:text="afassa"
              android:padding="50dp"
              android:id="@+id/text4"/>


    <View android:layout_height="2dp"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:id="@+id/line"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text4"
          android:background="@android:color/white"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly place TextView above ListView no need to add header, its seems like a header

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/ll" >

<TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="header"
    android:padding="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/text4"/>

    <View android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/line"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text4"
        android:background="@android:color/white"/>

    <ListView android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/lv"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: I this case, header will not scroll.

Answer (score 0):

You need to format your  header view - `test.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="afassa" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/line"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#ffffff" />

</LinearLayout>
```